# [object Object error]

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flex4

im a newbie in programming and developing a simple application in flex4 with coldfusion as my back end and MYQSl as my database.

im trying to output my database information in a text input field in flex by using remoteObject(cfc).

The information is being provided by a database using a query and an array collection. I'm just unsure how i go about taking the queried array collection information and display it into TextInput Fields. I hope that explains it a little better and I look forward to any input that could help me out

sample code:

```
<fx:declarations>
<mx:RemoteObject id="myService" destination="ColdFusion"
source="newVirtualJaialai"
result="resultHandler(event)"/>
</fx:declarations>

<mx:Button label="Get Data" initialize="myService.getBranchName()" x="50" y="50"/>

<mxataGrid dataProvider="{myData}" id="dataGrid" />
<mx:FormItem label="Username:" >
<s:TextInput id="username" {myData}/>
<s:Label />
</mx:FormItem>
```

Comment: It looks like your sample code is missing.

Comment: Your datagrid is incorrect.  Should be `mx:DataGrid` not `mxataGrid`

Comment: Hey not sure if you're still trying to get feedback on this but when you post code into stack overflow you should just paste the entire block of code into the text area then select all the text that's part of the code and hit the little code button above the text area (this threw me initially, not the best user centered design).  Looks like you have some issues with your code but without being able to see what you really have it's hard to say what in particular needs to be changed, also a screenshot ideally or explanation of the output will help (if errors include error # and describe line #)

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding `MyData` as dataProvider for your grid, I can suppose that `MyData` is collection/array, and when you are trying to bind it to `text` (`:String`) property of your `TextInput` you are getting your "[object Object error]" (actually this is not an error, try `_anyObject_.toString()` and you will get the same), so you need to bind some property of an item of this collection. If you want to display data of item that was selected in your grid, you can use `text="{dataGrid.selectedItem._someProperty_}`".